# clickhouse-client - inserting large volumes of data fail with memory outages

Tags: clickhouse

I have a bunch of processes loading TSV data ( a few hundreds of terabytes ) into clickhouse.

```
clickhouse-client --host=10.2.5.129 --port=9000 --query=INSERT INTO FS_20191211_0858 FORMAT TSV --send_timeout=30000 --receive_timeout=3000
```

At some point I can see that with 10 concurrent processes in 5-10 minutes each of `clickhouse-client` consumes about 10GB of RAM ( resident ) and after few more minutes OS kills them all.

Is there any way to restrict memory per clickhouse process?

`--max_memory_usage` doesn't seem to apply to client.

Comment: *clickhouse-client --help* shows these params that define memory restrictions: *--max_memory_usage_for_all_queries*, *--max_memory_usage_for_user* and *--max_memory_usage*. Maybe make sense to use them together?

Comment: max_memory_usage is a limiter. It does not reduce memory usage.

Try --max_insert_block_size=100000 --min_compress_block_size=500000 --max_compress_block_size=500000